# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen version 5.6.X does not have IDataContractResolver

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle, datacontract, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

---

I am trying to update all the dependencies of a template .NET Core 3.1 WebApi.
I found this breaking change between Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen 5.5.1 and 5.6.1, in which it seems they have moved IDataContractResolver interface from Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen but I havent find more information about where it could it be know, or if it is deprecated.

Could someone tell me what is happening?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be due to a dependency on "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft", according to [this comment](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1901#issuecomment-737158275) on a GitHub issue:

Try explicitly adding the "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft" NuGet package with the same version as you are using for "Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen".